# How can a guest user access a Disk mounted on my system

Tags: permissions

The admin user has mounted an internal HDD at `/media/admin/Storage`

A guest user was created using `sudo adduser guest`

But guest user is unable to access a subfolder in `/media/admin/Storage/subfolder`

I have tried everything from `chmod 777 subfolder` to `sudo chown guest subfolder`

Nothing works, I always get access denied.

Comment: nevermind i figured it out:

Comment: sudo mount --bind -o ro /media/admin/Storage/subfolder subfolder